# How I validate this kind of a number

Tags: php

I'm looking for a function or some logic that will validate a 10 digit long phone number. I'd like to make sure that the number is exactly 10 digits, no letters, no hyphens etc.. And also need to check first digit of the number start with 0.

```
Eg: 0714556260
```

**UPDATE**

```
$test = 0714556260;

if (preg_match("|^[0-9]{10}$|", $test)) {
      echo 'valid';
} else {
    echo 'not valid';
}
```

Comment: `strlen` and `strpos` are some of the functions you can use for your purposes.

Comment: [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: There's already lots of answers here using regexes, and has been closed as a duplicate of a question with lots of answers about regexes - but nobody discusses the advantages / weaknesses of regexes in relation to other methods (FWIW I do think that regexes provide the best solution - but maybe other people would benefit from knowing why)

Comment: The following will strip out all non-numeric characters from the input: `preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", "+0-867-5309");` then you can use one of the regexes in the answers to validate the number itself.

Comment: BTW most of the answers here and on the other question don't even provide any details on the specifics of the implementation nor do they mention support for edge cases such as using ITU dialing prefixes / other punctuation.

Comment: Why I asked this, could I get a solution without regexes. But every answers come up with regexes. check I update question using regexes but its not work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "0714556260";
if (preg_match("|^[0-9]{10}$|", $str))
    echo "ok";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match('/^0\d{9}$/', 0714556260) ) {
    // OK
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to validate your phone number in preg_match function:

```
/^0\d{9}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
$test = 0714556260;

if (intval($test) && preg_match($test,"/^0[0-9]{9}$/")) {
      //do stuff
}
```